# remove string from specific string to specific string

Tags: c#, string

i have a string like this

```
string test = "aaaaa start bbbbbbb end ccccccc start dddddd end";
```

I want to remove every character that are between "start" and "end" string so the resultant string will look like this

```
result = "aaaaa startend ccccccc startend";
```

Comment: So, what's the question? If you know what you have and what you want, just do it.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal, this is not a code factory site.. why don't you show us what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Regex.Replace("(?<=start)(.*?)(?=end)", string.Empty);
```

Comment: why do you use on the `start` the `<=` and not `=`?

Comment: @M.Schena because I don't want to remove `start` - `<=` for text before, `=` - for text after

Comment: thank you - i think i'll have a closer look at Regex funcionalities

Comment: thanks but its not working on special string like 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Abc" style="border:1px solid red;" />
    <input type="text" />

<!-- start -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:56310/10f49cd3b3c442e3957af6e2217d4c8a/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- end -->
</body></html>

Comment: If you want to set html instead of `start` and `end`, you should escape special symbols with `\` symbol. For example - `\(` instead of `(`